# How do I add a Babel plugin to a create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app

I'm following LearnCode.academy video tutorial and on video #7 at some point the tutor/presenter add the following code

```
@connect((store) => {
    return {user: store.user.user, tweets: store.tweers.tweers}
})
```

I understand I need to configure Webpack by adding `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` but `create-react-app` is not showing any of the configuration files. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could* eject for decorators it is completely unnecessary and comes with all downsides of ejecting (you don't get future updates to the tooling automatically).

Instead I recommend either using learning resources that don't rely on experimental features (which decorators currently are), or learning how to write equivalent code without them.

For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

export default connect((store) => {
    return {user: store.user.user, tweets: store.tweers.tweers}
})(MyComponent);
```

If you can't figure out how to write some example without decorators, create a new question and link to it in comments, and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you'll need to run the [eject script](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) to get all the configuration, and to change it from its defaults (*this is irreversible, backup before attempting!*). To do this, run:

```
npm run eject
```

This should add all the configuration files into your project, such as the Babel where you can add the plugin.